# Hash map returns null in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm using java `HashMap`:

```
public static HashMap<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

when I print the values:

```
System.out.println(config.toString());
```

the result is:

```
{key1 = val1, key2 = val2}
```

but when printing a key:

```
public String returnConfigByKey(String key){ 
        String result = "";
        result =(String) config.get(key); //key = key1
        System.out.println("result " + result);
        return result;
    }
```

the result is:

```
result null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the key definitely has a value associated with it? Can you check again with `key.trim()` ?

Comment: btw. you need no typecast (String).

Comment: it could be that the key does not exist. Also what is confusing me is `(String) config.get(key);`, why do you type cast if your `HashMap<String,String>` is defined this way? this leads me to an assumption that there could be something off.

Comment: Look like this just a misunderstanding, you code look fine.Please recheck the key.

Comment: We need to see more of your code in order to help... since `config` is a global variable, the mistake could be somewhere ^^

Comment: Yes, config.containsKey(key) returns false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HashMap.toString()` does not add a space after they key.

Therefore the keys in your map are `"key1 "`and `"key1 "` both ending with a space. You should be able to retrieve the value with `config.get("key1 ")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
HashMap<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put("key1", "val1");
config.put("key2", "val2");
System.out.println(config);
System.out.println("result " + config.get("key1"));
```

*Output*

```
{key1=val1, key2=val2}
result val1
```

As you can see, the `result` prints fine, but the print of the Map does *not* show any spaces around the `=` sign.

So, to see what you showed:

```
HashMap<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
config.put("key1 ", " val1");
config.put("key2 ", " val2");
System.out.println(config);
System.out.println("result " + config.get("key1"));
```

*Output*

```
{key1 = val1, key2 = val2}
result null
```

This exactly mirrors what you see, and shows that the problem is trailing space in the key.